# Failed to locate a binder for interface

Tags: android, eclipse

Can anyone help. I am making a simple weather app in android. I know first two error,but don't know about last one.

```
10-25 16:44:11.666: E/ActivityThread(1448): Failed to find provider info for com.google.plus.platform  
10-25 16:44:11.949: E/libEGL(1448): validate_display:255 error 3008 (EGL_BAD_DISPLAY)  
10-25 16:44:12.379: E/chromium(1448): [ERROR:interface_registry.cc(99)] Failed to locate a binder for interface: autofill::mojom::AutofillDriver
```

Comment: Did you find something?

Comment: No, But it should be library related issue.

Comment: I have the same problem and it is related to the AdMob instance I have. I haven't found the exact problem though.

Comment: Any luck? I am getting   "E/chromium: [ERROR:interface_registry.cc(104)] Failed to locate a binder for interface: autofill::mojom::PasswordManagerDriver"   this error. While loading some script in a webview.

Comment: @Kaustubh I'm having the same issue here, did you find something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Third error, possible due to the server being offline, therefore the URL not being loaded. Look at how you handle the WebView for that particular case. I might be wrong, ran into the same error a while ago, and I remember that's what it was.

Comment: I am developing weather app so here server is online at both side. I have checked URL and API key by JSONLINT. My app is working fine now but it show errors in Logcat.

Comment: If it helps anyone, aeroplane mode was on on my device. The Facebook login web view gave this error. It turned off aeroplane mode off and it worked fine, that is, once I got internet connectivity.

Answer (score 3):

Resolve this issue

```
    @Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    webView.onPause();
    webView.pauseTimers();
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    webView.resumeTimers();
    webView.onResume();
}
```

Comment: It's work in my case. The problem only occur if i run the app on the emulator

Answer (score 1):

I start getting exactly same error when i updated sdk and play services version. App works fine but getting this error on logcat. I think its admob related but not really sure.

Comment: This error is not related with Admob. I have solved Admob problem,Now its working fine. But still I am getting this error - "failed to locate a binder for interface".

Comment: I have no idea for the 2 first messages, but at least the 3rd one `E/chromium: [ERROR:interface_registry.cc(99)] Failed to locate a binder for interface: autofill::mojom::AutofillDriver` is related to AdMob. In my case it appears every 60 secs when ad refreshes. But the ads are displayed correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use `webView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true)`. In most of cases this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Enable JavaScript in the webview. By default JavaScript is disabled in the webview. After enabling JavaScript problem solved for me.

```
WebSettings webSettings=webView.getSettings();
webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
```

Comment: It does not work for me. Still have error after enabled JavaScript.

Comment: I don't use webview, its in my ads that is causing this...which is a webview but I don't implement webview anywhere else.

Answer (score 0):

Error Solved: I had same error and it was caused closing the loading **"Grade build running"** before the Apk is installed on my Emulator....I tried everything to fix but failed until i created another project and transfered my files to the new project.Hope it works for you too.

Answer (score 0):

I think that becouse you are using the Admobe test ID

Comment: i have the same problem with my new project and when I try to add the Admobe ID test  withe somme changes , the message apear again  I will confirm that when I have a real ad ID ,